# How to define the range of IPs using DHCP?

Tags: installation, command-line, server, dhcp, maas

I am new to installing ubuntu 12.10 MAAS. I want to set up a DHCP server to define the range of ips for clients. I am not able to do this on 12.10 while on 12.04 this was simple to perform. Please if anybody knows, tell me what to do to set up DHCP.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The Ubuntu Server Guide has a clear and succinct explanation of DHCP server operation.  [DHCP Server Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/serverguide/dhcp.html)

From the guide example configuration:

```
# minimal sample /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
 range 192.168.1.150 192.168.1.200;
 option routers 192.168.1.254;
 option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2;
 option domain-name "mydomain.example";
}
```

Where the configuration says, `range 192.168.1.150 192.168.1.200;`, you can insert the lower and upper IP bound for allocation.